# How to correctly set layout_width and layout_weight of textview horizontally?

Tags: android

I want to have a listview and there are header.xml and row.xml file in my app.
Both of them are linear layout and with 6 children textviews.
The first textview is ID and I would like to minimize it(still visible) because it is not important to the user.

Code(header.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="time"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Food"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Rating2"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Rating"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is that now the ID textview became completely disappeared. I supposed the higher the layout_weight is , the smaller the view get(in the case of width= fill_parent).
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

So add `android:visibility="invisible"`